# Select the value of radio buttons in datalist

Tags: c#, asp.net

its only selecting the first radio button value which is Excellent. its not going on the next condition ..please help me out... as soon as possible

```
  protected void btnsub_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int counter = 0;

            foreach (DataListItem item in dtl.Items)
            {
               RadioButtonList rbb =(RadioButtonList) item.FindControl("rb");


                if (rbb.SelectedValue.ToString() == "Excellent")
                {


                    string lblText = ((Label)item.FindControl("qid")).Text;

                    con.Open();
                    string q = "insert into eval values('" + empno + "','" + regno + "','" + coursename + "','" + courseno + "','" + semesterno + "','" + lblText + "','" + rbb.SelectedValue + "')";
                    cmd = new SqlCommand(q, con);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();
                    counter++;


                }
                if (rbb.SelectedValue.ToString() == "Good")
                {
                    string lblText = ((Label)item.FindControl("qid")).Text;
                    con.Open();
                    string q = "insert into eval values('" + empno + "','" + regno + "','" + coursename + "','" + courseno + "','" + semesterno + "','" + lblText + "','" + rbb.SelectedValue + "')";
                    cmd = new SqlCommand(q, con);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();
                    counter++;

                }
                if (rbb.SelectedValue.ToString() == "Average")
                {


                    string lblText = ((Label)item.FindControl("qid")).Text;
                    con.Open();
                    string q = "insert into eval values('" + empno + "','" + regno + "','" + coursename + "','" + courseno + "','" + semesterno + "','" + lblText + "','" + rbb.SelectedValue + "')";
                    cmd = new SqlCommand(q, con);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();
                    counter++;
                }
                if (rbb.SelectedValue.ToString() == "Below Average")
                {
                    string lblText = ((Label)item.FindControl("qid")).Text;
                    con.Open();
                    string q = "insert into eval values('" + empno + "','" + regno + "','" + coursename + "','" + courseno + "','" + semesterno + "','" + lblText + "','" + rbb.SelectedValue + "')";
                    cmd = new SqlCommand(q, con);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();
                    counter++;

                }
                if (rbb.SelectedValue.ToString() == "Poor")
                {



                    string lblText = ((Label)item.FindControl("qid")).Text;
                    con.Open();
                    string q = "insert into eval values('" + empno + "','" + regno + "','" + coursename + "','" + courseno + "','" + semesterno + "','" + lblText + "','" + rbb.SelectedValue + "')";
                    cmd = new SqlCommand(q, con);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();
                    counter++;

                }
                if (counter == 15)
                {
                    Response.Redirect("details.aspx");
                }



        }
```

Comment: Strongly suspect you are missing the `!IsPostBack` condition in your `Page_Load` when you bind your _DataList_.

Comment: Yeah that condition was missing. Working now. Thanks alot